# Android - Modify timbre of a voice

Tags: android, voice, voice-recording

I have an app which records the user's voice. Now what I want to do is to modify the timbre of that recorded voice. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A few answers are nessecary to close in on the problem:
Did you write the app yourself? If yes, which framework did you use?

I'll go ahead and assume you recorded the voice in your own app in android. If you are familiar with npm, the package manager, it supplies a free plugin to modify your voice-recording exactly the way you want it to:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/timbre

Timbre.js provides a functional processing and synthesizing audio in your web apps with modern JavaScript's way like jQuery or node.js. It has many T-Object (Timbre-Object) that connected together to define the graph-based routing for overall audio rendering. It is a goal of this project to approach the next generation audio processing for web.

```
<script src="timbre.js"></script>
<script>
    T("sin", {freq:880, mul:0.5}).play();
</script>
```